# What is the difference between .addCase() and .addMatcher()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was using redux toolkit. What got me confused in CreateReducer is that I can't quite understand the difference between .addCase and .addMatcher?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `addCase` will run the reducer if the dispatched action's `action.type` field *exactly* matches the string that you provide
- `addMatcher` will run the reducer if the callback function you provide returns `true`, and it's up to you to decide how the matching behavior works.  Typically this is done by looking to see if the `action.type` field is a *partial* match, such as `return action.type.endsWith("/pending")`

Answer (score 6):

To add more clarity to popular explanations: **`builder.addCase` can be viewed as a shorthand for `builder.addMatcher`, where an action is matched by its `type` property**. So, the following two pieces of code are functionally equivalent:

1.

```
export default createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(actions.openModal, (state, { payload }) => ({ ...state, modalData: payload, isModalOpen: true }))
    .addCase(actions.closeModal, (state) => ({ ...state, isModalOpen: false }));
});
```

2. 

```
export default createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addMatcher(
      ({ type }) => type === actions.openModal.type,
      (state, { payload }) => ({ ...state, modalData: payload, isModalOpen: true })
    )
    .addMatcher(
      ({ type }) => type === actions.closeModal.type,
      (state) => ({ ...state, isModalOpen: false })
    );
});
```